# Replace the keyword with the whole content of another file

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I write a bash script to replace the keyword with the whole content of another file.
Here is the command I use:

```
sed -i "s/CONTENT/$(cat $pathB)/" $pathA
```

A file

```
Here is my introduction:
CONTENT
Thank you.
```

B file

```
I'm OOO.
I'm 10 years old.
I like play baseball
```

Result A file

```
Here is my introduction:
I'm OOO.
I'm 10 years old.
I like play baseball
Thank you.
```

But this will show error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `r` command to append the content of file then delete the line containing the pattern:

```
sed -i -e "/CONTENT/r $pathB" -e '//d' $pathA
```

The reason why your `s` command fail is because it is expanded to:

```
sed 's/CONTENT/Im OOO.
Im 10 years old.
I like play baseball' $pathA
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works!!